# Adapter between OData and ElasticSearch

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, odata

I started using ElasticDB to store the data, the frontend has OData queries to fetch the data from DB (OData with MongoDB was used previously). I am in search of some middleware/Adapter/Plugin type of code which can convert OData queries to Elastic Queries without changing UI Request URLs. 
Please suggest if there is anyway doing this in .Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Olastic](https://github.com/Hevelian/hevelian-olastic) which provides OData services for Elasticsearch, based on [Apache Olingo](http://olingo.apache.org/).

Comment: But this is for Java. I am searching for .Net core. Is there any similar Nuget in .Net ?

Comment: Olastic does not seem to be being maintained, judging by the github page